# ¿Cómo pasar de una aplicación de windows forms a un archivo de excel?

Tags: c#

una simple pregunta. ¿Cómo podria pasar la información de una aplicación de c# a un documento de excel y así mismo a un pdf?

Comment: Hola Cristian. Por favor indica qué has intentado y dónde tienes problemas. Este tipo de cosas se encuentran en muchos tutoriales en línea.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Para generar un excel en .net recomendaria librerias basadas en `openxml` como ser

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

[SpreadSheetLigth](http://spreadsheetlight.com/)

Si puedes evita usar las librerias del propio Office estas estan basadas en COM y son para problema. Bueno salvo que las uses por medio de

[NetOffice - MS Office in .NET](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/documentation)

que aporta algun tipo de mejora para no lidear directamente con los problemas de las dll basadas en `COM` (por sino Office define librerias que no son .net)

---

Para generar pdf se usa otro tipo de librerias, las mas conocidas es [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/)

[iTextSharp - Introducing Tables](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables)

**Nota**: No he puesto ejemplos en código de como usarlas porque estas librerias tiene muy buena documentacion, ademas no se cual de todas las que he mencionado vas a seleccionar